# Recuperar texto de un SELECT y almacenar en $_POST

Tags: php

Cómo puedo recuperar el valor texto de un `select` y almacenar en `$_POST` para luego guardarlo en `bd`:

```
 echo "<option value=".$row['id'].".>".$row['concat']."</option>";
```

Quiero guardar el valor que viene en `concat`, mediante `POST`.

Comment: ¿Qué `name` tiene el `select`?  Si tiene `name="miSelect"` entonces recuperas el valor con `$_POST['miSelect']` en el servidor.

Answer (score 5):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

document.getElementById("ver").addEventListener('click', function(){

let htmlElement = document.getElementById('data');

let valor = htmlElement.value;
let i = htmlElement.length;
let elemento = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

var textoElemento;
while(i--){
 if(valor == elemento[i].value){
  textoElemento = elemento[i].textContent;
 }
 
}

if(textoElemento == ''){
 console.log('No ha selecionado ninguna opcion');

}else{

let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
let data = new FormData();

data.append('option', textoElemento);

http.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
  let post = http.responseText;
   alert(`Array de option: ${post}`);
  }
 }
 http.open('POST','url',true);
 http.send(data);
 }
});


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<select id="data">
<option value="0" hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">Opción 1</option>
<option value="2">Opción 2</option>
<option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>

<br>

<button id="ver">TEST</button>

<body>
<html>
```

Para poder testear pones el fragmento de codigo en php

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

En la parte del AJAX cambiar "url" por la direccion de tu fichero php para obtener la respuesta o confirmar el valor de tu select enviado, en esta parte:

```
http.open('POST','url',true)
```

De esta forma puedes obtener el texto de un select en $_POST

Answer (score 2):

Para capturar el **texto** y no el **valor** de tu `select`, te puedo sugerir `jQuery`. *En el siguiente snnipet te dejo un ejemplo de cómo funciona*.

```js
//al cambiar el valor del select
$('#opcion').change(function(){
  //asigna lo que tengas en el texto del select a una variable 
  var opcionSeleccionada = $('#opcion option:selected').text();
  //luego lleva ese valor al input con clase "opcion"
  $('.opcion').val(opcionSeleccionada);
})

$('#numero').change(function(){
  var numeroSeleccionado = $('#numero option:selected').text();
  $('.numero').val(numeroSeleccionado);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" action="archivo.php">
  <select id="opcion">
    <option value="0" hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <!-- el siguiente input lo puedes ocultar agregando el atributo hidden -->
  <input type="text" class="opcion" name="opcion" required><br>
  <select id="numero">
    <option value="0" hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="100">Número 1</option>
    <option value="200">Número 2</option>
    <option value="300">Número 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="numero" name="numero" required><br>
  <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Solo debes reemplazar el código `HTML` con tu código `PHP`, la siguiente línea por ejemplo:

```
<option value="1">Opción 1</option>
```

La reemplazas con tu código:

```
echo "<option value=".$row['id'].".>".$row['concat']."</option>";
```

Lo importante es que envías el valor del `input` a tu archivo `PHP` y en el, lo recuperas así:

```
$opcionSeleccionada = $_POST['opcion'];
```

Si tienes dudas, comenta.

**Edición:** Para dos o mas `select`, lo que puedes hacer es diferenciarlos con un `id` o con un `class` *como prefieras*, lo demás es copiar el código y cambiar los `id` ya que no deben existir dos elementos con el mismo identificador en el DOM.

Comment: esta buena esta solución me sirve, pero que pasa si tengo dos select como puedo llamarlo a cada uno?

Comment: Perdón por tardar en responder, estuve fuera un par de días... Edité la respuesta para que tengas un ejemplo de cómo funciona con dos o más `select`.